# Which permissions bypass/override ACLs?

Tags: permissions, acl

I know that some permissions will cause ACL checks to be skipped on certain operations/entities, for example:

- `view all contacts`: skip ACLs for View operation on any Contact.
- `edit all contacts`: skip ACLs for Edit operation on any Contact.
- `edit all events`:  skip ACLs for Edit operation on any Event.
- `access all custom data`:  skip ACLs for View operation on any Custom Field.
- `administer civicrm`: skip all ACLs.

Are there others?

Comment: My assumption was always any with 'all' would bypass any ACL.